# Android custom dialog and soft input

Tags: android, window-soft-input-mode

I have a dialog

```
if(this.oDialogo==null) {
    this.oDialogo = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
}

this.oDialogo.show();
this.oDialogo.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_stuff);
```

Inside, i have one EditText and two buttons. 
When I click on the EditText, and the Keyboard shows, BUT the dialog is hidden behind.

If I don't set the style for the dialog, it moves up and down when opening or closing the keyboard.

I set

```
this.oDialogo.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Still stays behind the keyboard.

Can anyone point me how to handle the dialog so it moves with the keyboard?

Comment: I have already faced this problem. as i found that soft input keyboard does not resize full screen or no title bar windows. So all the attributes of resizing or panning window while keyboard is showing/open does not have any effects on the full screen windows. as you can try changing themes to dark etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have seen that as well, except for the no titlebar. I managed to resize windows (Activity) while they have no title bar, I could not find the documentation that explains how the soft input resizes dialogs :(

Comment: It will be great for me if you can show me your window resizing code... as i am still searching for this

Comment: Its not like it has code, if I don't set a style, the dialog moves with the soft keyboard, but it has margins and title and stuff...